# What was Nezu stuffing into his briefcase?

Tags: akira

In the film, after burning loads of documents with his aides, a tank barrels into his estate and Nezu (over)stuffs a briefcase with papers before fleeing.

What were these papers? They did not appear to be money, and if they were documents that needed to be destroyed, why would he have taken them with him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I remember that scene.  Those documents appeared to be bond certificates, stock certificates, and/or other financially worth keeping documents.
[images of stock certificates](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+do+stock+certificates+look+like&biw=1920&bih=981&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7pq_S4fzPAhXpqFQKHUt4BLkQsAQIQw)
[images of bond certificates](https://www.google.com/search?q=What+do+bonds+look+like&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU_OTe4fzPAhVjlVQKHYr0AAwQsAQIJg&biw=1920&bih=981#tbm=isch&q=bond+certificates)